# python: Is there a way in python to delete the old .pyc before running the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyc

It seems that sometimes when I pull from the git the old `.pyc` runs instead of the new pulled `.py`  file is there a way to automatically clear the `.pyc` file so it runs always the fresh version ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The old `.pyc` is automatically cleared by Python, provided the modified date on the `.py` file is newer.

You could manually delete all `.pyc` files in a directory structure with:

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

and Python will re-create them as modules are imported. You can also run:

```
python -m compileall .
```

to force a compilation.

Comment: I don't commit them, I don't know exactly how git does time the files

Comment: Ah, I see; you pull *older* `.py` files from git thus the newer `.pyc` files are used instead of the changed source.

Comment: It seems it times them the time of the pull, I don't know what I done wrongly when it happened

Comment: Yes, git sets the modified time to the time of *commit*; your `.pyc` files on the other hand match whatever the modified time was of the `.py` file was at time of compilition. If you modify a `.py` file, run python, then roll back to an older version of the `.py` file, the `.pyc` file is not necessarily updated.

Comment: Its hard to investigate what happened post factum, better to apply solution, +1 and accept for the answer,

Answer (score 1):

Another option to prevent the creation of `.pyc` file is to pass options -B to python

```
python -B file.py
```

`-B` option from `man`:

```
-B     Don't write .py[co] files on import. See also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE.
```

also you can specify it at the beginning of the `.py` file with [sha-bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/bin/python -B
```